# Inject ConStr to Linq to SQL Class in DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I'm writing a simple 3 tier ASP Web Forms app, how can I inject my connection string into my DAL to the LINQ to SQL Class

I believe this is pulling the con info from the App.Config in the DAL

```
    public LNQDataContext() : 
            base(global::bcDAL.Properties.Settings.Default.TM10_ArchiveConnectionString, mappingSource)
    {
        OnCreated();
    }
```

is there a way I could modify this to LINQDataContext(string conStr) ??  I really want the admin to be able to set this in the web.config (not have it hard coded in a dll) should he have to move stuff around.

Or any other insightful alternatives are welcome, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataContext class generated for you via the DBML file is a partial, so just extend it with your own class that is named the same and add whatever additional constructor you need.  However, I'm not sure why you think the connection string is hard coded with what you have.  Dragging tables onto your DBML surface from the Server Explorer already adds a connection string to your web/app.config.  That's what `global::bcDAL.Properties.Settings.Default.TM10_ArchiveConnectionString` is pointing to in your example.

Comment: thanks what you described is what I have been attempting to do without success, if its in the app.config in the DAL it will not be accessible to change once the application is compiled, no ?  Hence I want the weblayer to push down the value pulled from the web.config

Comment: You're right - if you have a separate DAL project with the DBML file then the app.config for that project gets the connection string - which is totally silly since .dlls don't get app.configs.  But, like kman0 says, just copy that setting over to your web.config.  But, if you change the web.config at runtime, you clear out the whole app pool, so maybe overloading your constructor is best.  Up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply copy your connection string from the app.config of your data layer to the web.config in your presentation layer.  The app will find it in the web.config upon execution.